# Convert list of values into list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

i have a list of values like the following:

```
l = [qeqw, qqweqw, qweqeqe ,qeewqewq]
```

How can i convert the list into a list of strings like:

```
l = ['qeqw', 'qqweqw', 'qweqeqe' ,'qeewqewq']
```

Comment: What is that a list of? Are those object names?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[str(item) for item in l]
```

Comment: Did you want the variable **names** turned into strings?

Answer (score 1):

if your list consists of variables you can use this hack but if some other variables have values from the variables in list you'll have them in resulting list as well:

```
l = [name for name in globals() if globals()[name] in l]
```

if your list consists of objects which actually have name attributes you can use this approach:

```
l = [e.__name__ for e in l]
```

And if you just want to convert values to `str`:

```
l = [str(i) for i in l]
```

Comment: Since you do not know what kind of objects `[qeqw, qqweqw, qweqeqe ,qeewqewq]` are, you just made up the output. What if the objects in the does not support str? What object type did you use for the 'example'?

Comment: i made some changes to my answer, first hack is not 100% but might work @dawg

Comment: This will produce a runtime error (Python 2.7.10) if not used in a function.

Comment: The first one... the second doesn't work at all. `(int object has no attribute '__name__')`. The third just outputs `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (if objects set to ints).

Comment: @l'L'l your request/suggestion is useless since code was working with ints before you even started

Comment: @l'L'l you don't understand the question and the answer. What dawg said i corrected long time ago

Comment: it's not if you understand the subject, but whatever, i'm giving up talking to you

Answer (score 0):

First, the construction of the list replaces the names you used in the list with their values:

```
>>> a,b,c=1,2,'three'
>>> li=[a,b,c]
>>> li
[1, 2, 'three']
```

There is no universal or acceptable method to associate a given value back to a name in Python for most objects.

There are exceptions. Many callable objects (functions, methods, modules, classes but not class instances) have a `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> import os as noname_module
>>> noname_module.__name__
'os'
>>> def func(): pass
... 
>>> f=func
>>> f.__name__
'func'
>>> m=[].append
>>> m.__name__
'append'
>>> class O:
...    pass
... 
>>> O.__name__
'O'
```

However, most Python objects **do not** have a `__name__` attribute:

```
>>> a=1
>>> a.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> s="string"
>>> s.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> f.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> O().__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: O instance has no attribute '__name__'
```

The `str` function will produce a string representation of the object:

```
>>> [(type(e), str(e)) for e in (a,s,f)] 
[(<type 'int'>, '1'), (<type 'str'>, 'string'), (<type 'float'>, '1.0')]
```

But only if the `str` method is defined for that object:

```
>>> o=O()
>>> str(o)
'<__main__.O instance at 0x10bcc23f8>'
```

There is a 'hack' of looping through locals() or globals() to try and associate a name with a value. However, this has many issues.

First, what about the case of:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=1
>>> c=1
>>> d=1.0
>>> [n for n in globals() if globals()[n]==1]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']      # 1.0 and 1 are equal in Python's mind
>>> l=[a]
>>> [n for n in globals() if globals()[n] in l]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']      # ambiguous and incorrect...
```

You can add the name to your own objects:

```
>>> o=O()
>>> o.__name__=O.__name__
>>> o.__name__
'O'
```

But that won't work for most immutable built-in types..

So just accept it: There is no definitive way to associate a value back to an unambiguous name in Python unless it has a `__name__`

---

That said, to further the 'hack' you can try:

```
def v2n(o):
    try:
        return "'{}'".format(o.__name__)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    li=[n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is o and not n=='_']  
    if len(li)>1:
        return "Value of '{}' is ambiguous. Could be any of {}".format(str(o), ", ".join(["'{}'".format(e) for e in li]))
    elif len(li)==1:
        return "'{}'".format(li[0])
    else:
        return "No name"
```

And try that:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=1
>>> c=1
>>> f1=1.0
>>> f2=1.0
>>> f3=2.0
>>> class O: pass
>>> def func(): pass
... 
>>> f=func
>>> print '\n'.join([v2n(_) for _ in (a,b,c,f1,f2,f3, O, O(), f)])  
Value of '1' is ambiguous. Could be any of 'a', 'c', 'b'
Value of '1' is ambiguous. Could be any of 'a', 'c', 'b'
Value of '1' is ambiguous. Could be any of 'a', 'c', 'b'
'f1'
'f2'
'f3'
'O'
No name
'func'
```

Kinda works, but it is hit or miss.

If your algorithm relies on getting the name of the object (other than a callable, module or class) -- you probably need to revisit how you are approaching the problem.